# Error: Range-based 'for' loops are not allowed in C++98 mode

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, codeblocks

So I'm following the tutorials on this page: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/
But I'm having trouble doing a range/based for loop. I found this page:
[GNU GCC compiler updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12822851/gnu-gcc-compiler-updating)The answer there says I should open "Project" and "Properties". But when I try that, the "Properties" option is grayed out with no explanation:
http://imageshack.com/a/img571/4371/xd1x.png
So.. how can I activate range/based for loops?

Comment: The PNG link does not work.  (This is why it's suggested to embed error messages in the question, rather than linking to external sites)

Answer (score 20):

Pass `-std=c++11` flag to the compiler. Certainly GCC should be fresh enough (>=4.7) to support all these modern standards. For CodeBlocks 13.12: Settings -> Compiler -> Tab "Compiler Flags" -> Option "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ [-std=c++11]"

Comment: I'm going through a beginner's tutorial, which means I'm a complete noob here. What does it mean to pass a flag to the compiler?

Comment: Well, specify that string among other compiler options in the command line, like this: `g++ -std=c++11 -o test_executable test_source.cpp`

Comment: You're overestimating my knowledge, I have no idea where to write that

Comment: How do you compile your code? In an IDE? Try to locate a place in the IDE menu (Settings?) where compiler invocation is configured.

Comment: Indeed, I use Code Blocks! Sorry, forgot to mention that. I posted a picture in the first post showing I can't access the properties for some reason

Comment: GCC 4.7 supports some of C++11 but by no means all of it. Regex support is only available from 4.9 and many other features were introduced in 4.8.

Comment: But the range based for loop is in since 4.6 IIRC

Answer (score 7):

In **Dev-Cpp 5.11** Simply you can click on **Tools**>**Compiler Options**>**Settings**>**Code Generation**>(and in last option)**Language standard(-std)** select from dropdown (**ISO C++ 11**).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The above given solution of using `-std=c++11` didn't work for me.

This is the target and version detail of my compiler.

`gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu`

When I tried, this is what happened.

`$ g++ -std=c++11 program.cpp
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-std=c++11’`

This solved the problem for me.

`$ g++ -std=c++0x program.cpp`

Answer (score 3):

If you faced this error in **Code::Blocks**, this might help you -

Click on Settings -> Compiler -> Compiler Settings -> Compiler Flags

Under the "General" section, check [✓] the box beside :
**Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]**

[image: Check image for reference]

Answer (score 2):

Both of these:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o test_executable test_source.cpp
g++ -std=c++0x -o program program.cpp
```

worked for me.

Only thing to do after compiling is to execute the `test_executable` (in the first case) as `./test_executables` or program (in the second case) as `./program`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `QT5.5`, you can achieve it by adding following lines in your `.pro` file.

`CONFIG += c++11`

Answer (score 0):

Using the above solution
`g++ -std=c++0x program.cpp`
works. However, the command needs to be modified slightly in order to run the program with the common command:
`./program`

I used
`g++ -std=c++0x -o program program.cpp`
and all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is doing this, in Dev C++:

1. Go to the "Tools" Option
2. Select "Compiler Options"
3. Click "Settings"
4. Click "Code Generation"
5. Go to "Choose Language" and select "ISO C++11"

Then your problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

in first time, if you have Dev-C++
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin`, you must add this route to the path
then use the next command in cmd.

`g++ -std=c++11 -o outprogram code_source.cpp`

this command in your project directory.