# CLion disable C++98 mode in favour of C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, ide, clion

I'm trying to compile some code using C++11 only syntax in JetBrains CLion, so I wish to disable C++98 mode. I followed the instructions accordance of [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859183/error-range-based-for-loops-are-not-allowed-in-c98-mode), but am unable to get it working.

In order to achieve this goal, I went to ALT + SHIFT + F10 and passed the argument `-std=c++11` in *Program Arguments*.

Upon building again, C++98 mode still seems to be enabled.

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/Zarthus/Documents/test/command.cpp: In constructor 'Command::Command(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >)':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Zarthus/Documents/test/command.cpp:25:32: error: range-based 'for' loops are not allowed in C++98 mode
     for (std::string command : commands)
                                ^
```

in the code

```
Command::Command(std::vector<std::string> cmds)
{
    for (std::string command : cmds)
    {
         addCommand(command);
    }
}
```

Whilst I'm fairly certain the issue lies not within my code ([IdeoneC++11](http://ideone.com/UHrpz8) versus [IdeoneC++98 (4.8.1)](http://ideone.com/aMOJRs))

Image: [CLion Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNPer.png)

What I'd imagine is the compilation string (per comments):

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\Zarthus\.clion10\system\cmake\generated\6dd8bed\6dd8bed\Debug --target testProject -- -j 4
```

So it does not appear it includes my content.

I've not a lot of experience with other JetBrains IDE's, but from what I could tell they're mostly the same.

Is anyone able to reproduce this? Should I send feedback to JetBrains that this may not be working 100% (it's still an early release build)? Or am I just botching it up and is there an user error here?

Thanks!

Comment: Never used CLion, but is there a way to see the what the g++ compiler is actually doing, i.e. a "verbose" mode?  That way you can see if your arguments are being picked up but ignored, never picked up, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I added a C:\cygwin64\bin\cmake.exe string - I'm not sure if that is exactly what you're looking for, but it's the best I could find. As for extra debug information - I could not find such option.

Comment: An IDE usually has a window or some means so that you can see the entire command line string that the compiler is using.  Otherwise you're compiling blindly.  The `cmake` uses a file, and inside that file has the command-string used by the compiler.  Basically what you need to figure out is the exact command string used by the compiler, and then work from there.

Comment: Fairly obvious what you are doing wrong, you don't want to pass -std=c++11 to your own program.  Keep looking, has something to do with CMake configuration.

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie, I fixed it by adding `add_definitions(-std=c++11)` to the EOF of CMakeLists.txt - I wasn't aware CMake is basically my 'compilers' arguments. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been resolved by adding `add_definitions(-std=c++11)` to the end of `CMakeLists.txt` instead of in ALT+SHIFT+F10's command line arguments.

Comment: Neither `set(CXX_STANDARD 11)` nor `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")` would work for me, but this did. Thanks!