# Tuple not recognized by Clion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

CLion doesn't seem to recognize c++ `tuple`s, although I can build and run my program from the terminal.

When trying to build, I only get "Build failed", while all the members of `tuple` are highlighted and I'm getting "Can't resolve namespace member tuple" (same with `tie` and `make_tuple`).

Here is my simple test:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tuple>
std::tuple<int,int> testTuple();

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a, b;
    std::tie(a,b) = testTuple();
    std::cout<<a<<" "<<b;
    return 0;
}
std::tuple<int,int> testTuple()
{
    return std::make_tuple(0,1);
}
```

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(testTuple)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER, /usr/bin/g++-4.8)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

set(SOURCE_FILES "src/main.cpp")
add_executable(simplification ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: You don't get it, do you? [MCVE] as usual please, including verbatim error messages. BTW the [tag:clion] tag is probably irrelevant here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ this only has to do with `clion` - doesn't have much to do with `cmake`, I think. While CLion does rely on cmake, it is not a cmake - related issue. I am running cmake on the same file in the terminal and it does work.

I supplied more information related to the fail, although there isn't much more that I can find relevant.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that being said, I think this is
Minimal: can't think of a simpler test program.   Complete: this is all the code, and all the information that I have. The inspector is highlighting it as an error, the build fails in clion but works in command line, and the only message when building is "Build failed".     
Verifiable: fire up CLion, copy-paste the code and the CMakeLists.txt and it can be tested

Comment: @BujancaMihai is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28592565/955273) of any use?

Comment: @BujancaMihai - I don't agree with the downvotes - but this is SO so you have to expect it. It might be a good idea to add a screenshot showing the code in CLion and the build failure?

Comment: @BujancaMihai another possible [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25900342/955273)

Comment: @BujancaMihai [More possible help](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/comments/3scwxg/c_how_do_i_get_clioncmake_to_use_c11/)

Comment: @SteveLorimer sorry for not replying earlier. I can add a screenshot, but there is really no more information that it would provide, I think. All the build says is "build failed". Other C++11 features like range-based loops are recognized and work.
A thing I noticed is that Clion labels `#include<tuple>` as an unused import statement. So it might be that somehow it does include the functions in `<tuple>` but doesn't recognize the functions as belonging to the header

Comment: @BujancaMihai what version of what compiler are you using? Is the CLion IDE using a different compiler to the once you are on the command line?

Comment: @BujancaMihai please also add screenshot from `settings | build, execution, deployment | toolchains`

Comment: @BujancaMihai you might also want to [enable verbose build output](http://superuser.com/questions/1065550/show-full-build-output-in-clion)

Comment: @SteveLorimer I just updated Clion to 2016.1.2, and the issue is solved for me

Comment: @BujancaMihai nice one!

Answer (score 0):

For implementing such features as code-competition, jump to definitions and so on features `CLion` has it's own `c++` parser.
So if your code compiled, but `CLion` show some kind of errors,
go and report bug to jetbrain (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP)

Comment: I'm trying to first determine if it's something that I did wrong (maybe there was some configuration step in CLion that I'm not aware of?) before submitting it as a bug

Comment: @BujancaMihai `CLion` take information about how to compile your project from `CMakeLists.txt`. Not important which part fails - parsing cmake file, or it's internal parser, both parts have one root - bug in `CLion`.